# Stored Procedure to Update Records by based on the values of other table in loop

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have two tables.

**Table A**

```
   -------------------------------------------
    id    | date      | shiftId | activityId |
    -------------------------------------------
    1      2018-09-09     1          100
    2      2018-09-09     1          101
```

**Table B**

```
        ------------------------------------------------------------------
        id    | reading   | resourceId   |date  | shiftId | activityId 
        ------------------------------------------------------------------
        1        10.0            10       2018-09-09     1 
        2        11.0            11       2018-09-09     1
```

Now, I want to update Table B activityId from Table A, querying Table A on **shiftid** and **shiftDate**.

How to write stored Procedure to update Table B in loop?

I tried  below query.

```
create or replace FUNCTION Update_TableB_ActivityId()
Returns Void as $$
Declare 
rec RECORD;
query text;
activityId integer;
BEGIN
query := 'select * from TableB where "activityId" is null;
FOR rec IN execute query
LOOP
execute 'select "activityId" from TableB where "date"=rec."date"' into activityId;
execute 'Update TableB set "activityId"=activityId where "id"=rec."id"';
END LOOP;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Mysql or postgresql ? And what have you attempted so far ?

Comment: Show us your current stored procedure attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Use update with join, so not required stored procedure for loop

For mysql:

```
UPDATE tableb
    JOIN tablea on tablea.shiftid=tableb.shiftid and 
tablea.date=tableb.date
SET tableb.activityid=tablea.activityid
```

For postgres:

```
UPDATE tableB
SET tableb.activityid=tablea.activityid
FROM tableA
WHERE tableA.shiftid=tableB.shiftid and 
    tableA.date=tableB.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is POSTGRESQL STORED PROCEDURE



    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schemaName.updateactivityid()
      RETURNS text AS
    $BODY$
    declare
    c_shiftId   int;
    c_activityId int;
    c_date       date;
_curs cursor FOR select distinct shiftId,activityId,date from schemaName.TableA; ----Cursor
    BEGIN
    OPEN _curs ; --- Opening Cursor

    LOOP
    FETCH _curs INTO c_shiftId,c_activityId,c_date;  
                                                  --- Fetching Cursor Data into Variables

    EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
    RAISE NOTICE 'shiftid %%%',c_shiftId;
    RAISE NOTICE 'activityid %%%',c_activityId;
    RAISE NOTICE 'date%%%',c_date;

   
Update table schemaName.TableB SET  TableB.activityId=c_activityId where TableB.date=c_date and TableB.shiftId=c_shiftId;   ---Update Statement
    
    END LOOP;
    Close _curs;
Return 'Y';
    END;
    $BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
      COST 100;
    ALTER FUNCTION schemaName.updateactivityid()
      OWNER TO postgres;
```